# "docker ps" does not show PORT details of a Kubernetes-controlled container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have two Redis containers running on a K8s worker node. One is controlled by a Deployment (redisdeploymet1) and the other is a standalone Docker container that I created locally on worker1 (outside the knowledge of K8s)“:

```
root@worker1:~# docker ps | head -1 ; docker ps  | grep redis | grep -v pause
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
bc7b6fd74187   redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago    Up 4 minutes    6379/tcp   nervous_vaughan
3c6fc536e265   redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 minutes ago   Up 42 minutes              k8s_redis_redisdeploymet1-847d97
```

Why shouldn’t we see the PORT details on both entries above? I have actually tested them; both are indeed listening on 6379.

My ultimate goal is to identify which ports a specific Pod is listening on. Let's say the Dockerfile is not available.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the redis service yaml to your question, which was deployed to your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: You shouldn't use `docker` to try to control Kubernetes-managed containers.  Can `kubectl describe pod` give you the information you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker port` command.

- `docker port <container_id>`: List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container

Comment: "docker port" does not show anything if port mapping has not been defined. The output is blank for both above-mentioned containers.

Comment: @Nabadan I thought you were expecting this one, anyway, then you cannot get the port without knowing it somehow(ex: from dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks. Both containers are created by the same Docker runtime in worker1. It would be interesting to know what the possible reason behind such design is.